# How do I install Harmon.ie Enterprise version for Outlook on a Mac (desktop)

Tags: harmon.ie

Trying to install Harmon.ie enterprise on my Macbook air. I want to use it on the desktop application for Outlook. How do I do this?

Steve

Comment: It appears there is a mac version. Have you downloaded it? Have you tried installing it? Have you looked at the documentation? Where are you stuck installing it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Outlook on MAC is support via App for Outlook (OWA).  You may find additional details in the Administration Guide
You can get it from Microsoft Store.
See: https://harmon.ie/getting-started-harmonie-app-outlook